Book series about a girl with a white spirit wolf
I remember reading a young adult or children’s book series that featured a girl with a spirit wolf helper. The main character worked at a pet adoption center, and she found a lake in the woods behind the adoption center with a glowing rock at the bottom.
If anyone knows of any series that is similar to this description, please let me know!

In roughly which year/s did you read these books? Also, you you recall anything about any of the covers?
